# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o248.showString

Tags: pyspark

My Code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import os
import sys
schema=StructType([StructField('name', StringType()),
           StructField('Age', IntegerType())])
data=[('a',1),('b',2)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

After that i am getting an error

An error occurred while calling o248.showString.

Comment: Welcome to SO! For me your code works (with PySpark 3.32). Could you please add the complete stacktrace to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in first cell of notebook.

```
import findspark

findspark.init()

findspark.find()
```

This will initialize the spark in jupiter notebook

makes sure to create separate environment for pyspark in Jupiter or vscode

[image]